# How to numerically obtain the first ten eigenvalues of a 3D Sturm-Liouville problem

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method, eigenvalues

I'm trying to numerically obtain the first ten eigenvalues of a 3D S-L problem via NDEigenvalues but with no success. The problem is given by

```
Lx=2;
Ly=2;
Lz=2;

k[x_,y_,z_]=Piecewise[{{1, 0.5<=y<=1.5&&0.5<=x<=1.5&&0<=z<=2}}, 0.25];
w[x_,y_,z_]=Piecewise[{{1, 0.5<=y<=1.5&&0.5<=x<=1.5&&0<=z<=2}}, 0.000339266];

NDEigenvalues[{D[k[x, y, z] D[ψ[x, y, z], x], x] + D[k[x, y, z] D[ψ[x, y, z], y], y] + D[
      k[x, y, z] D[ψ[x, y, z], z], z] + μ^2 w[x, y, 
      z] ψ[x, y, z] == 0, ψ[0, y, z] == 
   0, ψ[Lx, y, z] == 0, ψ[x, 0, z] == 0, ψ[x, Ly, z] ==
    0, ψ[x, y, 0] == 0, (D[ψ[x, y, z], z] /. z -> Lz) == 
   0}, ψ[x, y, z], {x, 0, Lx}, {y, 0, Ly}, {z, 0, Lz}, 10]
```

Nonetheless, Mathematica gives as output the input itself. Anyone could help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For example like this:

```
Lx = 2;
Ly = 2;
Lz = 2;

k[x_, y_, z_] = 
  Piecewise[{{1, 0.5 <= y <= 1.5 && 0.5 <= x <= 1.5 && 0 <= z <= 2}}, 
   0.25];
w[x_, y_, z_] = 
  Piecewise[{{1, 0.5 <= y <= 1.5 && 0.5 <= x <= 1.5 && 0 <= z <= 2}}, 
   0.000339266];

\[Mu] = 1;

NDEigenvalues[{
  D[k[x, y, z] D[\[Psi][x, y, z], x], x] + 
   D[k[x, y, z] D[\[Psi][x, y, z], y], y] + 
   D[k[x, y, z] D[\[Psi][x, y, z], z], 
    z] + \[Mu]^2 w[x, y, z] \[Psi][x, y, z]
  , DirichletCondition[\[Psi][x, y, z] == 0, 
   x == 0 || x == Lx || y == 0 || y == Ly || z == 0]}, \[Psi][x, y, 
  z], {x, 0, Lx}, {y, 0, Ly}, {z, 0, Lz}, 10]

(*
{-1.22419, -4.40255, -5.29783, -5.29783, -7.19205, -7.19205, \
-7.19414, -8.68989, -9.20316, -9.53589}
*)
```

**Update:**

After some comments back and forth, this is a better approach:

```
ClearAll[\[Mu]]

Sqrt[NDEigenvalues[{w[x, y, z] D[phi[t, x, y, z], 
      t] == -Inactive[Div][
      k[x, y, z] Inactive[Grad][phi[t, x, y, z], {x, y, z}], {x, y, 
       z}], DirichletCondition[phi[t, x, y, z] == 0, 
    x == 0 || x == Lx || y == 0 || y == Ly || z == 0]}, 
  phi[t, x, y, z], t, {x, 0, Lx}, {y, 0, Ly}, {z, 0, Lz}, 10]]

(* {1.72004, 2.91152, 3.84061, 3.84061, 4.38555, 4.53164, 4.53164, \
5.30524, 5.63385, 5.83603} *)
```

Comment: I'm curious, what is the reason that `NDEigenvalues` not accept boundary conditions given without `DirichletCondition`?

Comment: Note, that the FDM type Dirichlet conditions are not the only issue. There is an `==` in the equation and there is a `Derivative` to make a Neumann zero bc that need to be fixed. Never the less, I think I can make FDM type Dirichlet conditions for for `NDEigensystem` for version 12.2.

Comment: Thanks. Personally I find it an odd syntax, when compared to `NDSolve`. Why can't it take an equation?

Comment: @KraZug, because we are not dealing with an equation: For example, you can not have a load term. How would you explain that?

Comment: But you are have an equation in that you are solving it to be equal to $\lambda \Psi$, no?

Comment: Yes, but we do not make use of that term in the formulation.

Comment: The ```\[Mu]^2``` term represents the eigenvalues in my problem. I did not understand why you set it equal to one and not any other value. I think, since it is the term representing the eigenvalues, it should be a variable in this problem that i do not know how to handle. I thought that i had to use FEM method or something like that to achieve my goal

Comment: @AdamReis, then you need to remove that term from the operator. See the documentation for [NDEigensystem](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDEigensystem.html), third point in the details section. But I am not sure I understand your set up then.

Comment: I want to solve the S-L problem given by: ∇.[k(x,y,z)∇[ψ(x,y,z)]]+μ²w[x,y,z]ψ(x,y,z)=0. According to NDEigensystem third point in the details section, the function solves: "∇²ψ(x,y,z)=μψ(x,y,z)". So, in order to obtain the results I want, I should write the NDEigensystem command:


```\[Sqrt]NDEigenvalues[{-Div[
     k[x, y,z] Grad[\[Psi][x, y,z], {x, y,z}], {x, y,z}]/w[x, y,z], 
   DirichletCondition[\[Psi][x, y] == 0, 
    x == 0 || x == Lx || y == 0 || y == Ly|| z == 0]}, \[Psi][x, y, z], {x, 0, 
   Lx}, {y, 0, Ly},{z,0,Lz}, 10]```

?

Comment: I am comparing the results of NDEigenvalues with the results of the solution via GITT, an numerical-analytical approach. Nonetheless, the results do not match when the weight function (i.e., w[x,y,z]) is different of the constant function 1. I believe that is because I did not get how to correctly compute it.

Comment: @AdamReis, does this help: `Sqrt[NDEigenvalues[{-Inactive[Div][
     k[x, y, z]/
       w[x, y, z] Inactive[Grad][\[Psi][x, y, z], {x, y, z}], {x, y, 
      z}], DirichletCondition[\[Psi][x, y, z] == 0, 
    x == 0 || x == Lx || y == 0 || y == Ly || z == 0]}, \[Psi][x, y, 
   z], {x, 0, Lx}, {y, 0, Ly}, {z, 0, Lz}, 10]]`? What are the first few eigenvalues? Can you send a link to GITT?

Comment: The first ten eigenvalues obtained by GITT are: {8.55461, 11.6068, 15.0932, 15.0932, 15.7916, 17.2182, 17.2182, 20.2894, 20.5529, 20.5529}. The result obtained by your suggestion is different, but thanks anyway! I guess we just have to correctly write (-∇.[k(x,y,z)∇[ψ(x,y,z)]]/w[x,y,z])==(μ^2)ψ(x,y,z). I tried `Sqrt[NDEigenvalues[{-Inactive[Div][ k[x, y, z] Inactive[Grad][\[Psi][x, y, z], {x, y, z}], {x, y, z}]/ w[x, y, z], DirichletCondition[\[Psi][x, y, z] == 0, x == 0 || x == Lx || y == 0 || y == Ly || z == 0]}, \[Psi][x, y, z], {x, 0, Lx}, {y, 0, Ly}, {z, 0, Lz}, 10]]` but did not work.

Comment: @AdamReis, sorry for getting back so late. I think the proper way to write this would be: `Sqrt[NDEigenvalues[{w[x, y, z] D[phi[t, x, y, z], 
      t] == -Inactive[Div][
      k[x, y, z] Inactive[Grad][phi[t, x, y, z], {x, y, z}], {x, y, 
       z}], DirichletCondition[phi[t, x, y, z] == 0, 
    x == 0 || x == Lx || y == 0 || y == Ly || z == 0]}, 
  phi[t, x, y, z], t, {x, 0, Lx}, {y, 0, Ly}, {z, 0, Lz}, 10]]`, though that still does not return the values you suggest.